# $P$ poset: $ J \subseteq P$ is join-dense iff $\forall x \in P$, $\,\,\, x = (\downarrow x \cap J) $

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $\mathrm{P}$ be a poset: $ \mathrm{J} \subseteq \mathrm{P}$ is join-dense in $\mathrm{P} \iff \forall x\in \mathrm{P}$ we have $x =\bigvee (\downarrow x\cap \mathrm{J})$

about this implication "$\Rightarrow$", since $\mathrm{J}$ is join-dense in $\mathrm{P}$, $\exists\,\, \mathrm{S} \subseteq\mathrm{J}$ s.t. $x = \lor \mathrm{S}$, so I am trying so show that $\mathrm{S} = \downarrow x\cap\mathrm{J}$: $\,\,$let $b\in\mathrm{S} \Rightarrow$ $b \le \lor\mathrm{S} = x$, so $b \in \downarrow x \Rightarrow b\in \downarrow x\cap\mathrm{J}$. $\,\,\,\,$ Now let $c \in \mathrm{I}\cap\mathrm{J}$  $\Rightarrow c \le x = \lor \mathrm{S}$ $\,\,\,\,(...)$

any idea how to complete it? Or maybe there is a different path to follow?

The implication $"\Leftarrow"$ is easy because of the assumption, by putting $T := \downarrow x \cap J \subseteq J$, then $\forall x \in P \,\, \exists \,\, T \subseteq J$ s.t.$\,\, x= \bigvee T$, that is the definition of join-dense set.

Comment: It is not necessary that $S=I\cap J$. For example, if $x\in J$, then $S=\{x\}$ is enough. But it seems enough that $S=I\cap J$; my doubt is what is the definition and the result you wish to prove here. Apparently the definition is in the first paragraph and you want to prove the result in the title?

Comment: @amrsa it's the exercise 2.39 from "Introduction to lattices and order" by Davey and Priestley : Let $P$ be a poset: $J \subseteq P$ is join-dense in $P \iff \forall \,\, x \in P\,\,$ we have $x = \bigvee (\downarrow x \cap J)$. $\,\,\,\,$ I am struggling with the $\Rightarrow$ implication.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy.

Since $J$ is join-dense in $P$, for every $x \in P$ there exists $A \subseteq J$ such that $x = \bigvee A$.
(This is just the definition of join-dense set.)

In these conditions, it is clear that $A \subseteq {\downarrow}x$.
Thus we can take $A$ to be ${\downarrow}x \cap J$, and obtain $x = \bigvee ({\downarrow}x \cap J)$.